# is there an open source algorithm for a fixed limit holdem

Tags: texas-hold-em, software

I'm looking for an AI algorithm in any programming language for studying. The simple - the better.  I've read that [Polaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris_%28poker_bot%29) is the best implementation for a fixed limit holdem so far. I'm looking for something simple, that will reveal logic behind betting\folding\etc.

Or maybe there's a resource online that show calculations like this:
if I have AK of hearts and flop is 9-8-7 and I'm on BB position and 5 players total. SB checks. your turn is...

Comment: The resources and info in this Stackoverflow question may help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506167/building-a-texas-holdem-playing-ai-from-scratch

Comment: @JeffreyBlake: whoa, whoa, whoa! That link is *not* comment material but is imo answer-worthy! Today I learned about the "poker" tag on SO

Comment: @o.v. Ok - converted :)

Answer (score 2):

The resources and info in this Stackoverflow question may help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506167/building-a-texas-holdem-playing-ai-from-scratch

Comment: +1. There are good resources in those answers... Unfortunately, the OP there didn't answer to my comment/question; I didn't expect that...